Serializability order in locking protocols and timestamp-based protocols
The Database System Concepts book says this about the serializability order of transactions in different protocols.

The locking protocols that we have described thus far determine the order between every pair of conflicting transactions at execution time by the first lock that both members
of the pair request that involves incompatible modes. Another method for determining
the serializability order is to select an ordering among transactions in advance. The
most common method for doing so is to use a timestamp-ordering scheme.

If every individual transaction follows the 2PL protocol, then in whatever fashion they are interleaved, they will always produce a serializable schedule and the serializability order is determined by the lock point of the transactions when they are being executed.
But, in timestamp-based protocol, suppose we have three transactions $A$, $B$ & $C$ with timestamp $T_A$ $\lt$ $T_B$ $\lt$ $T_C$. The serializability order should be in the order of their timestamps i.e., $A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$ $\rightarrow$ $C$. However, suppose if $A$ has to rollback, then it will be assigned new timestamp, and the order of their timestamp will be $T_B$ $\lt$ $T_C$ $\lt$ $T_A$. The new serializability order will be $B$ $\rightarrow$ $C$ $\rightarrow$ $A$.
This is where I'm having trouble understanding $:$ How can timestamp-based protocols give us a serializability order in advance before the execution when the order keeps changing during execution of the transactions?
